# Grouping and Kendo Grid template not working

Tags: templates, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a tab strip inside the details template for my grid. It works fine until I decide to group my data, when I do the details template no longer works. During my investigation it turn out that the Id of the different tab strip has been set to null, while the tab strip that I opened retains their original Id. I am not sure why details template lost reference to the Id. Here are my code below.

Creating the grid

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("ChangeLog")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(m => m.ChangeDate2)
                .Title("Date and Time")
                .ClientTemplate("<span>#= formatUtcDateToLocal(ChangeDate2 ? ChangeDate : '' )#</span>")
                .Width("12%");
            ............................
        })
        .Filterable()
        .Selectable()
        .Sortable()
        .Groupable()
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Template(
                    @<text>
                        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-i-excel"></span>Export to Excel</a>
                    </text>
                 );
        })

       .Events(e => e.FilterMenuInit("resizeFilter")            
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
             .Ajax()
             .Read(read => read.Action("Data", "Log")
             .Data("buildParam"))
       )
       .DataBound("preselectCustomFilter"))
       .ClientDetailTemplateId("log-details-template")
       )
```

and this is how I define my details template

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="change-log-details-template">
<div>
   @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
  .Name("tabStrip_#=Id#")
  .Animation(animation => animation.Open(effect => effect.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
  .SelectedIndex(0)
  .Items(tabstrip =>
  {
      tabstrip.Add().Text("Old Value").Content("<div class='oldValue' style='height:137px;padding:10px''><span>#=OldValue#</span></div>");
      tabstrip.Add().Text("New Value").Content("<div class='newValue' style='height:137px;padding:10px'><span'>#=NewValue#</span></div>");
  }
  )
  .ToClientTemplate())
</div>
```

When I inspect the detail template before grouping I see that the Id is being correctly applied

```
<div class="k-widget k-tabstrip k-header k-floatwrap k-tabstrip-top" id="tabStrip_164317" ...>
```

After I do the grouping all the template not initialized before the grouping now contains null instead of the id

```
<div class="k-widget k-tabstrip k-header k-floatwrap k-tabstrip-top" id="tabStrip_null" ........
```

Any hints on what I need to do? Maybe redraw the grid?

**UPDATE**

Refreshing the grid via `.refresh()` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad. I needed a second pair of eye. I was using the wrong model. When I made the call to `.Read(read => read.Action("Data", "Log")` I was returning logModel which is the base model that the model I use inherits from. So on load when I was using the right model it has the Id property, but after the read I was returning the base model which did not, and that is why the Id is null. :D